# Angular.ui alert doesn't close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scope, alert

I'm use the Angular-ui and i want to create single alert. But Alert won't to close

```
<div ng-controller="AlertCtrl">

     <alert type="danger" close>i'm alert</alert>

</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

actually you don't even need a controller and a function if you place your message in the html:

```
<alert type="danger" close="bCloseAlert=1" ng-hide="bCloseAlert">i'm alert</alert>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only ever want to show one alert, you need to change your approach a little.

Your should pass a function from your AlertCtrl's scope to the "close" attribute, like this:

```
<alert type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert()" ng-show="alert != null">
    {{alert.msg}}
</alert>
```

*Note that your type, and the text of the alert, now reference an alert object.  Also note that I have added the ng-show attribute to only show the alert markup if the alert object is not null.*

And then implement that function in your controller, and define an alert object for it to manipulate:

```
$scope.alert = { type: 'danger', msg: 'im alert' };

$scope.closeAlert = function() {
    $scope.alert = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your html:

```
<div ng-show="hasError">
<alert ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index" type="danger" close="closeAlert($index)">{{error}}</alert>
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.hasError = false;
$scope.errors = [];

$scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
     $scope.errors.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Then, you can close each alert window.